# How to make $not regexp query work in Go?

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm having trouble implementing non-full text exclude search with golang and mongodb.

It's work in mongo shell:

```
db.collectionName.find({"comment":{"$not": /.*excludeThis.*/}})
```

It's don't work in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "regexp"

    "github.com/night-codes/mgo-wrapper"
    mgo "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

type (


    SomeStruct struct {
            ID      uint64 `form:"id" json:"id" bson:"_id"`
            Name    string `form:"name" json:"name" bson:"name"`
            Comment string   `form:"comment" json:"comment" bson:"comment"`
        }

    collectionStruct struct {
        collection *mgo.Collection
    }

    obj map[string]interface{}
    arr []interface{}
)

var (
    some = collectionStruct{collection: mongo.DB("somedb").C("somecollection")}
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(".*" + "exclude" + ".*")
    query := obj{"comment": obj{"$not": re}}

    result := []SomeStruct{}
    if err := some.collection.Find(query).All(&result); err != nil {
        log.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    log.Println("Result:")
    for k := range result {
        log.Printf("%+v\n", result[k])
    }
    log.Println("-------")
}
```

I'm getting error:

> Error: reflect.Value.Interface: cannot return value obtained from unexported field or method

Is here any way to make regex work or implement it in other way?

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with your regular expression. But you didn't show the code that's actually causing the error, so it's hard to help.  Please show relevant code.

Comment: You haven't included the definition of `SomeStruct`, so no, this isn't all the code.

Comment: It's all the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Now it does indeed look complete.

Comment: Did you try exporting `collection`?

Comment: All I did now in code section. If you wondering why there reflect error I guess it's somewhere inside mongodb driver. If I change collection to Collection results are the same.

Comment: Well the error is pretty clear that the problem relates to trying to use an unexported field (and not to your regular expression). It's unfortunate that the error isn't very specific about which unexported field you're trying to use. Best I can suggest is export everything, possibly one at a time, until the error goes away.

Comment: All fields in my struct is exported. I also made all variables like `some`, `re`, `result` and `query` exported so as structures but it's didn't change anything.
If i change `obj{"comment": obj{"$not": re}}` to let's say `obj{"comment": obj{"$not": obj{"$ne": "123"}}}` there is no error, that is why I said that problem with regexp passed to $not;

Comment: It looks like your problem might be with `obj` then. Try exporting that. Intuitively, that makes sense, as it's difficult for mgo to parse your query, if doing so requires traversing unexported types.

Comment: I already tried exporting literally everything in this file.

Comment: It does compile. I just copied this exact code from above and run it.
https://i.imgur.com/slir6lp.png

Comment: Oh indeed, it does compile. `gofmt` was removing an import erroneously for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any mongo servers, so I can't actually run it far enough to trigger your error.

Comment: Does the error you received have any extra information not included in the question? Such as a stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `obj{"comment": obj{"$not": bson.RegEx{Pattern: ".*" + "exclude" + ".*"}}}` instead of `obj{"comment": obj{"$not": re}}`